Unity - Android SDK & NDK download failed
I'm trying to build a Photon 2.0 sample for VR.
I just installed Unity 2022.3.39f1, and it completed partially.
Android SDK and NDK downloads failed. I checked the info-log.json under \UnityHub\logs, and found this error listed in multiple places:
{"...,"level":"warn","moduleName":"EulaFetcher","pid":15104,"message":"Failed to fetch eula for android-sdk-ndk-tools, at https://dl.google.com/dl/android/repository/repository2-1.xml"}
and:
{... "level":"warn","moduleName":"EditorManager","pid":15104,"message":"Could not fetch eula text for Android SDK & NDK Tools, reason:  AxiosError: unable to get local issuer certificate\n    at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (node:_tls_wrap:1535:34)\n    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)\n    at TLSSocket.emit (node:domain:489:12)\n    at TLSSocket._finishInit (node:_tls_wrap:949:8)\n    at ssl.onhandshakedone (node:_tls_wrap:730:12) {\n  code: 'UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY',}
I've tried restarting UnityHub with admin credentials, without success. I'm working with my work laptop on a home Wi-Fi network. I also downloaded the Android Studio, but wasn't sure how to use it in conjunction with Unity Hub.
Any tips on what might be wrong, or manual work-arounds?


Found this: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-sdksetup.html so if going the 'External tools for Android' route would make sure that the correct supported version of Android tools are available locally (and builds an 'Hello World' Android app) before connecting with Unity.

I turned off zscaler security temporarily and it was able to download.
